# Disable a <p:menuitem> during page loading

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsf, primefaces

I have a `<p:menuitem>` which directs the user to a new page, and it takes some time to load the page completely. Now I have this problem when the user clicks the menuitem again during page loading, the application gets broken (says it can't find some component to update). I haven't found the cause of the error yet but I think it would make sense to prevent the user from clicking on the same menuitem again before the page loading is completed, I have tried several ways but couldn't work it out. Where I'm currently going is as follows:

```
<h:form id="maninmenuform">
    <script type="text/javascript" >
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $("#ssss").click(function(){
                $(this).attr("disabled", true);
            });
        });
    </script>

....
 <p:menuitem id="ssss" value="#{msg['capacity.headline']}"
                       icon="ui-icon-note"
                       url="/page/workload/workloadOverview.xhtml"
                       rendered="#{loginBean.projectAccess()}" />
```

Could anyone have a look and see what's missing there? Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

From what i see, you're trying to disable it by attaching an onclick event once the page is full loaded.

I think you should set it as "disabled" from the start in your code : `<p:menuitem disabled="true" />`

And then add some JavaScript to remove disabled attribute :

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("[id='form:ssss']").removeClass("ui-state-disabled"); 
});
```

Where `form:s` is your `<h:form>` id followed by your `<p:menuitem>`id.

**EDIT :**

The above method doesn't restore click event and menu navigation.

To handle this, you need to to remove `disabled="true"` from your `<p:menuitem>` and replace with `<p:menuitem onclick="return false">`.

Then, replace JS with :

```
$(document).ready(function () {
     $("[id='form:s']").removeAttr('onclick');
});
```

**EDIT 2 :**

This code :

```
<h:form id="form">
  <p:menu>
    <p:menuitem id="s" value="Menu" onclick="return false" />
  </p:menu>
</h:form>
```

Generates this HTML :

```
<form id="form" name="form" method="post" action="/ogma/admin/test" enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded">
  <input type="hidden" name="form" value="form">
  <div id="form:j_idt36" class="ui-menu ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-corner-all ui-helper-clearfix" role="menu">
    <div tabindex="0" class="ui-helper-hidden-accessible"></div>
    <ul class="ui-menu-list ui-helper-reset">
      <li class="ui-menuitem ui-widget ui-corner-all" role="menuitem">
         <a tabindex="-1" id="form:s" class="ui-menuitem-link ui-corner-all" href="#" onclick="return false;"><span class="ui-menuitem-text">Menu</span></a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <input type="hidden" name="javax.faces.ViewState" id="j_id1:javax.faces.ViewState:0" value="8002603806970497135:4662901914508572407" autocomplete="off">
</form>
```

As you can see, the `<p:menuItem>` generates a `<a id="form:s">` HTML element with an attribute `onclick="return false;"`. This attribute prevents the user from being redirected to target URL after a click on this element.

That's why this JavaScript :

```
$(document).ready(function () {
     $("[id='form:s']").removeAttr('onclick');
});
```

Allows the element to handle clicks again once the page is fully loaded.

Comment: Just tried but didn't work - the menuitem is always disabled. It seems to me the statement  "$(this).attr("disabled", true/false);" somehow has no effect at all. Maybe it's not the right way to control the element in this case.

Comment: I just tried this and it still doesn't work. I used firebug to locate the element but I don't see the attribute "onclick". In this way, if I remove the javascript code and everything works as expected, nothing should happend when I click on the menuitem right?

Comment: Okay I see the "onclick" attribute, but somehow the script is still not working. Shall I put the <script type="text/javascript"> tag in or outside the form?

Comment: @friedrichx The script should be on the bottom of your page and you need to make sure jQuery is included.

Comment: Still no luck, now the menuitem is forever disabled. And btw "JQuery is already included on every page where you have primefaces components. No need to include again."

Comment: @friedrichx Please check your generated `<a>` element for the disabled menu match the jQuery selector which removes `onclick` attribute.

Comment: I checked - the id 'maninmenuform:ssss' is correct, and the "onclick='return false'" is always there.

Comment: Where exactly should I put the script tag? I checked the html source of the resulting page and the javascript code is not there.

Comment: The `<script>` tag should be in the result HTML regardless of where  you put in in your code. Restart your server or rebuild your project.

Answer (score 0):

define a flag in loginBean.

```
private boolean menuItemEnabled;

public boolean isMenuItemEnabled()
{
    return menuItemEnabled;
}
```

disable menuItem initially:

```
<p:menuitem id="ssss" disabled="#{loginBean.menuItemEnabled}" ... />
```

write a remoteCommand on page that will enable the menuItem.

```
<p:remoteCommand name="enableMenuItem" action="#{loginBean.enableMenuItem}"
    process="@this" render=":maninmenuform:ssss"/>
```

write the action method in the loginBean.

```
public void enableMenuItem()
{
    menuItemEnabled = true;
}
```

call the remoteCommand on page load.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    enableMenuItem();
});
```